# Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Occurs randomly

Tags: c#, tcp, firebird

I'm working on c# windows service that handles firebird database requests. My problem occurs at random moments (sometimes after 5 minutes, sometimes after just 4 calls to database), when I try to deserialize object on client application. It happens though only at specific position (stops at 18th byte in 54 byte array). Rest of the time the function returns a proper result.

---

I'm using this function to serialize single object

```
public byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, obj);
    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    byte[] rval = fs.ToArray();
    fs.Close();
    return rval;
}
```

I am not serializing any custom classes, only strings and numeric types (firebird api returns them as objects though).
I use this to deserialize:

```
public object ByteArrayToObject(Byte[] Buffer)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Buffer);
    stream.Position = 0;
    object rval = formatter.Deserialize(stream); <--- this thing drives me nuts.
    stream.Close();
    return rval;
}
```

and main fnct in client aplication. Sorry for ugly code,

```
    public List<object[]> ByteToList(byte[] data, int[] pomocnicza)
    {
        //pomocnicza table contains size of (original) particular column of list in bytes
        int size_row = 0;
        foreach (int i in pomocnicza)
        { size_row += i; }
        List<object[]> result = new List<object[]>();
        int iterator = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length / size_row ; i++)
        {
            object[] zxc = new object[3];
            int l = pomocnicza.Length/4;
            for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
            {
                byte[] tmp = new byte[pomocnicza[j*4]];
                System.Array.Copy(data, iterator, tmp, 0, pomocnicza[j*4]);
                object ffs = ByteArrayToObject(tmp);
                zxc[j] = ffs;
                iterator += pomocnicza[j*4];
            }
            result.Add(zxc);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

What is baffling me is that it works in most cases, but inevitably causes to throw an error. Thing that it happens on random makes pinpointing it harder. Please help.

---

@EDIT
This is how I read the input:

```
    public List<object[]> RetrieveSelectData(FbConnection dbConn, string SQLCommand)
    {
        using (var command = dbConn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = SQLCommand;
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var rows = new List<object[]>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var columns = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                    reader.GetValues(columns);
                    rows.Add(columns);
                }
                return rows;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then serialize with this function

```
    public byte[] ListToByte(List<object[]> lista, out int[] rozmiary)
    {
        int size= 0;
        rozmiary = new int[lista[0].Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lista[0].Length; i++)
        {
            byte[] test = this.ObjectToByteArray(lista[0][i]);
            size+= test.Length;
            rozmiary[i] = test.Length;
        }
        size*= lista.Count;
        byte[] result = new byte[size];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < lista[i].Length; j++)
            {
                byte[] tmp = this.ObjectToByteArray(lista[i][j]);                  
                tmp.CopyTo(result, index);
                index += tmp.Length;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What's byte array content when error occurs? If it can be reproduced you may also log everything (both server side and client side)...

Comment: where did `Buffer` come from when you called `ByteArrayToObject` ? A common mistake is to make a mess of stream-reading code, for example. Without seeing what comes before `ByteArrayToObject`, I am going to make the statement (from experience) that the problem here is **almost certainly** the input data, caused by incorrect reading.

Comment: In particular, from http://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html, the sections "Network packets: what you send is not (usually) what you get" and "Learning to read"

Comment: Byte array is containing data, position 18 in this array is of value 12 (bytes before it are not nulls or anything).  I can post the funct that I use to make entire array of bytes, but it probably won't do any good, it's just simple iteration taht helps me create array of bytes to send over tcp and an array that helps in decoding (contains specifics about the size of the objects in bytes).

Comment: I have read your blog, Marc, and I still havent ruled out a tcp packet loss, but on localhost it should be minor issue.

Comment: @user2383572 no, I don't think packet loss is the issue, and that blog doesn't say that; I strongly suspect you simply aren't reading the input correctly. I don't mean that insultingly; I mean that in the "I answer a lot of questions on sockets and serialization, and this is the number one cause of problem like this". So again: can you show the code **before** `ByteArrayToObject`, where you read data from the socket/stream?

Comment: I have edited the question, with all the function I use (except for similar one to ListToByte on client side, that does decoding).

Comment: @user2383572 the edit does not show the code that leads up to `ByteArrayToObject`, which again: is the interesting and relevant code

Comment: also, there's something very odd in the lengths; it seems to use only the first row to write per-field lengths, but it is by no means certain that every row will have the same size

Comment: Lengths are fixed in size for entire scope, that's not the issue (list contains only 6 elements, so). During our discussion I found though that bytes are shifted by 4 between client and server, now on a hunt for solutions.

Comment: @user2383572 and again, if you showed the code leading up to `ByteArrayToObject`, I could probably help you with that ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell edited, sorry for messy code, I'm fairly new to c#.

Comment: I have read this question (and the duplicate) multiple times, but I am still not really sure what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug. The code above works fine, but care for encoding in some cases(!), so feel free to use it. 
The problem laying in another part of a program, where I mistyped and send 4 bytes BUT the client app was told to receive 8, so in most cases it filled it in with zeros, but sometimes it got it from next pack of data.

It was @Marc Gravell and his blog that made me look over and over again to eventually find the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using above deserializing methods & also call them while getting stream from clientstream OR other streams.... skip it. try to use directly those streams with formatter. Like Below :

```
NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
Object src = (Object)formatter.Deserialize(clientStream);
```

Comment: I had to communicate with devices that use compact framework, I don't think the methods you posted are there.