# NetworkStream.Write() shifts buffer by 1 byte, causing exception "Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader."

Tags: c#, tcp, firebird

I have found the core mechanism in my other question
[Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Occurs randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886512/binary-stream-0-does-not-contain-a-valid-binaryheader-occurs-randomly)
It appears that networkstream object shifts entire buffer by one byte, inevitably causing Serialization Error later on (still on random, most of the time it works fine). 
Due to specifics of my project, most of the time I'll be sending small packets or bytes.

It seems to me I'm doing something wrong in principle, so here are my question:

What is the best method to send a serializable objects by tcp protocol? How to make sure the packets are received ? 
Although I haven't dont any research yet (this idea just popped in my head), maybe it's just better to serialize entire stream of data from FbDataReader (that behaves like DbDataReader object), and then deal with it on client side?

Comment: could it be some endianess issue?

Comment: I ruled  that out, both client and server are running on the same machine and under the same .net, besides serialization wouldn't even run in the first place (and it does, most of the time).

Comment: TCP itself makes sure the packets are received correctly. Also as this is essentially the same question as your other one, so I am voting to close it as a duplicate. The problem is either in your code, or there is a bug in the Firebird .net provider.

Comment: This question is either duplicate (without any information to find the bug), or it is too broad ("what the **best** serialization method?"). Better use a higher-level protocol such as HTTP or web-services anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with `NetworkStream`. And as MarkRotteveel mentioned, TCP takes care of receiving all data, and in the correct order.

Some databases require some additional configuration to ensure the data is stored/transmitted correctly. Also we've been having alot of issues with the .NET provider for firebird in the past, I wouldn't rule that possibility out.

You could try `Convert.ToBase64String()` and `Convert.FromBase64String()` before writing and reading to/from the database, and store them in a text column instead. If this doesn't provide a solution to the issue, it would at least give more insight to where things go wrong as you can view the database value more easily.

Comment: After some time and few modifications, I discovered two things:
1st, my conversion back and forth looped in just server has no errors whatsoever.
2nd, that while in debug mode, my problem doesn't occur, but yet when I fire each as standalone programs the error arouses rather quickly.

Comment: The forum post you link to seems to be a problem in a third party driver, not in Firebird itself (Embarcadero makes Interbase, not Firebird, and most likely they were doing things that work with Interbase, but not with Firebird). Although Firebird was forked from a version of Interbase, they have diverged in the last 15 years.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The way I read it the underlying problem was Firebird, but as I'm not sure and the link doesn't add anything to the answer, I will remove it.

Comment: Looking at the code in the other question, I am not sure if Firebird is actually involved in the problem at all, or if it is just a problem with serializing and deserializing data obtained from Firebird.